# Selinux: Managing ports; Semanage command not found

Tags: fedora, selinux

I'm having trouble configuring SELinux to allow sending mail.

Reading the SELinux documentation I've found I can manage ports via the `semanage` command, but the command can't be found.

Is there another way to manage ports using SELinux, or a way for me to find this command? **Worst case:** Is there a way to disable SELinux, or switch to permissive mode without rebooting?

I'm running Fedora.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELinux is a complicated beast I have managed to avoid so far (it's on the todo list somewhere!). However the one command most sysadmins will learn is the one to disable it:

```
setenforce 0
```

You can then use this command to check the status of SELinux:

```
getenforce
```

A quick google turned up [this page](http://joysofprogramming.com/install-semanage-fedora-rhel/) on the subject of installing semanage, looks pretty simple.

Comment: That definitely worked. Im testing to see if it solves my mail issue.

Comment: Mail still not working but at least now I know its not Selinux... Thanks for the help. Accepting answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty late (3 years on) but turning off selinux isn't the 'right' answer. You'll find semanage in the `policycoreutils-python` package, which dosen't seem to be installed by default.

However port forwarding *should* be handled by firewalld - the one time I needed to use semanage was to set the selinux flags for a samba share.I use the gui for firewalld, but `firewall-cmd --permanent [--zone=<zone>] --add-port=<port>[-<port>]/<protocol>` should add a port permanantly and `firewall-cmd --reload` should load it. As always, [RTFM](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD#Using_firewall-cmd) for more details.